# Unable to use "pip install scp" command in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python, scp

I am new to the ubuntu/linux world.

While try to run my python script I get the following error:
    root@ubuntu:/home/haris/Downloads/# python install.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "install.py", line 35, in <module>
import scp
ImportError: No module named scp
```

SO I tried to run the following command:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/haris/Downloads/ee-scale/tools/os-installer# pip install python-scp
Downloading/unpacking python-scp
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scp
No distributions at all found for scp
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How do I install scp on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2):

It's just the name - it's called "scp", not "python-scp":

Use `pip install scp`

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work? Are you able to download it with that command?

Comment: Yes, worked for me, no errors.

Comment: Aah! it turned out to be PROXY issue!
disabled it, ran, pip install scp
enabled it again

Alternatively I could have done:
pip install --proxy="user:password@server:port" scp

Comment: You should add a real answer yourself, just with what you say in the comment - and accept that answer. Otherwise, the question will stay open forever.

Answer (score 1):

Aah! it turned out to be PROXY issue! disabled it, ran, pip install scp enabled it again Alternatively I could have done: pip install --proxy="user:password@server:port" scp